# How to navigate back to the master screen from the details with Nav controller on Android

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, master-detail

I have the following nav_graph xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/users_fragment"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/users_fragment"
        android:name="com.package.UsersFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/users_fragment"
        android:label="UsersFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_users_fragment_to_profile_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/profile_fragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/users_fragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profile_fragment"
        android:name="com.package.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="ProfileFragment">
        <argument
            android:name="userId"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

The main activity xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.package.UsersViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/app_bar_layout"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

To navigate to the details I call:

```
val action = UsersFragmentDirections
    .actionUsersFragmentToProfileFragment(
        userId = user.userId,
    )
navController.navigate(action)
```

where `UsersFragmentDirections` is generated by the safe-args plugin.

The problem is that when I press back the master fragment is not shown: the activity is closed.
If in the action I use `app:popUpToInclusive="false"` then the back button does not work anymore.
What should I do to be able to go to the UsersFragment from the ProfileFragment when the user press back?

Comment: If you want to be able to go back to the `UsersFragment`, why do you have `app:popUpTo="@id/users_fragment"` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're popping users fragment while moving to profile fragment. So when you press back, there is nothing in the backstack and hence activity finishes..
So, to fix this issue you have two options:
1) Manually re-open/navigate users fragment
Or
2) Remove these two lines

```
app:popUpTo="@id/users_fragment"
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

Comment: If I remove the two lines or even just the second one then the back button does not work anymore

Comment: but it should go back to **users_fragment** as your start destination is `app:startDestination="@id/users_fragment"`. 
So, can't say much without seeing the full code